# allow access to folder through htaccess, not working in Chrome

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, http-status-code-403

I have this htaccess file for restrict the access of my domain for different files.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(docx|pdf|doc|txt)$ - [NC,F]
</ifModule>
```

My idea is to restrict the file downloads for unlogged users of my domain, but allow the downloads for logged users.

The code worked for all browsers, but since a few days ago, it doesn't work for Google Chrome. For Firefox, IE and Safari works perfectly.

I removed the cache and nothing, the error continues.

Any ideas? Were there any update for Google Chrome that affects my code?

Comment: Using `HTTP_REFERER` is not suggested because it can be spoofed. It is not secure at all. If you want to be able to control downloads you should do it in your server side code. e.g. though PHP or something.

Comment: Check webserver access log while you are browsing with chrome. You can find out what is the referer URL appears there.